# Is the decimals can be change when protocol updating?

Tags: protocol

[image]
I am confusing when I'm reading the write paper because the decimals is actually 6 now.

Comment: Please avoid using images if possible, which makes searching questions and answers from the context very hard.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the protocol amendment can change the number of decimals.  It would happen pretty unlikely, though.

The position paper and white paper are *historical* document written in 2014.  Even the updated parts in red are old and many details are now out of date.